# Here's a fun math/Zoom question for you all:

Tags: permutations, combinations

If I have 6 people in a group and each participant needs to meet each other in pairs of 2, how could I arrange Zoom Breakout rooms so that no one meets another twice? (3 Breakout rooms consisting of 2 people per session)

Here are the possible pairs I have (the letters represent initials of participants):
K x R, K x J, K x C, K x N, K x Z, R x J, R x C, R x N, R x Z, J x C, J x N, J x Z, C x N, C x Z, N x Z

So with this in mind, it should break down into 5 total sessions with 3 breakout rooms in each session and 2 participants per breakout room. I just can't seem to figure out how to configure it without duplicate people being in a session.

Comment: Terrible title.  Please rewrite it to refer to the *content* of the question.

Answer (score 1):

| Pair 1 | Pair 2 | Pair 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | CD | EF |
| AC | BE | DF |
| AD | CE | BF |
| AE | CF | DB |
| AF | CB | DE |

I solved it by approaching it as you would sudoko